# React Native Scroll View Conditional Render

Tags: react-native

In my app, I have a ScrollView that contains a bunch of images, but I would like the first item that is rendered in that ScrollView to be a 'plus' icon which would allow users to add more images. How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you use Flatlist instead of ScrollView? if you are just rendering some repetitive items you can use Flatlist and improve performance. if you can i have an idea to add your plus icon.

Comment: I wouldn't mind, but would Flatlist work similarly to Scrollview? Like vertical and horizontal scrolling?

Comment: yes they are same in scrolling, Flatlist are userd when you want to render same components. <FlatList data={[{ id: 1, imageUrl: "" },{ id: 2, imageUrl: "" },{ id: 3, imageUrl: "" },{ id: 4, imageUrl: "" },]} keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} renderItem={({ item, index }) => (<View style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}> <Image source={{ uri: item.imageUrl }} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }} />{index === 0 && (<View style={{ position: "absolute",left: 10, bottom: 10,width: 20, height: 20, backgroundColor : "red"}}><Text style={{fontSize : 15,color:"white"}} >+</Text></View> )}</View>)} />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a `FlatList` is better suited for your use case, as you are rendering a set of similar items.

If you switch to `FlatList`, you can use the prop `ListHeaderComponent`:

```
<FlatList
  data={myImageArray}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <MyImageComponent image={item} />}
  ListHeaderComponent={MyPlusButtonComponent}
/>
```